# Filter on laravel pivot table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have two tables in `Laravel` connected with a pivot table. The two tables are `users` and `roles`, and the pivot table is called `role_user`. The pivot table also contains two extra fields: `start` and `stop`. This way I can track which roles a `user` has had in the past.

Now I want to create a query that gets all `users` who currently have `role_id = 3`.

First I had used `WherePivot`, but apparently that is [bugged](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3215).

I have now made the following query using `Eloquent`:

```
Role::with('User')
    ->where('id', '=', '3')
    ->where('role_user.start', '<', date('Y-m-d'))
    ->where('role_user.stop', '>', date('Y-m-d'))
    ->whereHas('users', function($q){
        $q->where('firstname', 'NOT LIKE', '%test%');
    })
    ->get();
```

But somehow I am getting an error that the column start of the pivot table cannot be found. But I can confirm in `PHPMyAdmin` that the column is there.

This is the entire error:

```
Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'klj_role_user.start' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `klj_roles` where `id` = 3 and `klj_role_user`.`start` < 2014-06-02 and `klj_role_user`.`stop` > 2014-06-02 and (select count(*) from `klj_users` inner join `klj_role_user` on `klj_users`.`id` = `klj_role_user`.`user_id` where `klj_role_user`.`role_id` = `klj_roles`.`id` and `firstname` NOT LIKE %test%) >= 1)
```

Can someone tell me if I am doing something wrong or give me a hint where I should be looking now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is telling you that you are missing the `start` column in your pivot table `klj_role_user`.  What you should do is create the column.  If the column is already there, ensure you are using the correct database.

I've also simplified your query a little bit.  You don't really need a `whereHas` because you aren't trying to limit your roles by the users associated, but by the id, which in this case, you are using `3`.  A `with()` would work perfectly fine and `wherePivot()` seems to be working fine for me when used in conjunction with `with()`.

```
$role = Role::with(array('users' => function($q)
{
    $q->wherePivot('start', '>', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $q->wherePivot('stop', '<', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $q->where('firstname', 'NOT LIKE', '%test%');
}))->find(3);


foreach($role->users as $user) {
    echo $user->firstname;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that did work! You changed the `>` and `<` between `stop` and `start` though, I had to search a little to find that mistake. :p

Comment: Ohhh sorry haha, was messing around with that when working with my test data and forgot ot change it back.  Glad this worked out for you.