# Eloquent filter on pivot table created_at

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, many-to-many, eloquent

I want to filter the contents of two tables which have an Eloquent belongsToMany() to each other based on the **created_at** column in the pivot table that joins them. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001692/filter-on-laravel-pivot-table) SO question I came up with the following:

```
$data = ModelA::with(['ModelB' => function ($q) {
        $q->wherePivot('test', '=', 1);
    }])->get();
```

Here I'm using a simple test column to check if it's working, this should be 'created_at'.

What happens though is that I get all the instances of ModelA with the ModelB information if it fits the criteria in the *wherePivot()*. This makes sense because it's exactly what I'm telling it to do.

My question is how do I limit the results returned based on only the single column in the pivot table? Specifically, I want to get all instances of ModelA and ModelB that were linked after a specific date.

Comment: Use `with` and `whereHas` together to get what you need. Mind that you need to prefix your column with table name: `pivot_table.created_at` otherwise it will (likely) be ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, here it goes, since the other answer is still wrong.

First off, `wherePivot` won't work in `whereHas` closure. It's `BelongsToMany`s method and works only on the relation object (so it works when eager loading).

```
$data = ModelA::with(['relation' => function ($q) use ($someDate) {

    $q->wherePivot('created_at', '>', $someDate);
    // or
    // $q->where('pivot_table.created_at', '>', $someDate);

    // or if the relation defines withPivot('created_at')
    // $q->where('pivot_created_at', '>', $someDate);

}])->whereHas('ModelB', function ($q) use ($someDate) {

    // wherePivot won't work here, so:
    $q->where('pivot_table.created_at', '>', $someDate);

})->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Yeah, I was pretty sure I tried wherePivot() in the whereHas() already and it didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

You are using `Eager Loading Constraints`, which constrain only, like you said, the results of the related table.

What you want to use is whereHas:

```
$data = ModelA::whereHas('ModelB' => function ($q) {
    $q->wherePivot('test', '=', 1);
})->get();
```

Be aware that `ModelB` here refers to the name of the relationship.

Comment: `ModelB` refers to the relation name defined in `ModelA`, not the table name, and that't not the array, so no `=>`

Comment: deczo yes totally right, I will edit it. My bad, I looked at my code and since it was a lowercase plural word I assumed it was the table name :S